# Who are the earliest unlockable characters that will give me all the exploration powers in LEGO Harry Potter 2?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

Which unlockable characters in *LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7* are the earliest unlocks for all the exploration powers (such as Dark Wizard)?

Comment: Fastest to get or earliest level in the game?

Comment: @Pubby8 Wouldn't the earliest to get also be the fastest to get?

Comment: @CyberSkull — A character in the first level which requires a character from the last level to unlock is earlier, but slower, than a character from the middle of the game. There *were* a few such cases in HP1.

Comment: @BenBlank Oh, by level number. No, I mean by the _very first possible unlocks_ for each power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Strength** - Dudley: Year 1 level 1. Alternatively, use the super-strength red brick found in Hogwarts.
- **Dark Magic** - Bellatrix (Azkaban): Year 7 part 2, while exploring Hogwarts between missions she in the air over the field near Hagrid's house. Use the pink platform with Hermione to get the pumpkincopter, then use it to fly around and get Bellatrix.
- **Key** - Mrs. Cole: Year 7 part 2. Use dark magic in the diner kitchen to unlock her.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get Grindenwald young and old up the astronomy tower, year 7 part 2 as soon as you can walk free in Hogwarts, you need Hermione's pink platform. Also they're super cheap to buy I think like 200k each?

Comment: Year 7 Part 2 is hardly "early".

Comment: What does Grindenwald do again?