# Who knows Dark Magic?

Tags: nintendo-ds, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

When playing *Harry Potter Years 5-7*, I noticed there are things only Wizards with Dark Magic can interact with. I figure these are things I will have to go back and do later, as right now I don't have anyone in my party that can use Dark Magic.

Which characters in the game use Dark Magic? Who is the first one I can unlock, so that I can go back and get whatever it is from these areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the DS version is the same in this regard, it would be Bellatrix (see [this question for location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35235/9300)).

Answer (score 5):

On the DS version if thats what you're playing I would go for Alecto Carrow on price. You can also get Dolores Umbridge for the same reason she is cheap. But if you do have a lot of money to spend its Tom Riddle or Bellatrix LeStrange. Just a note.

- Alecto Carrow: $20,000
- Dolores Umbridge: $50,000
- Tom Riddle: $500,000
- Bellatrix LeStrange: $500,000

Answer (score 0):

Peter Petigrew is good because he is cheap.  He costs about $20,000.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Umbridge isn't a dark wizard. You don't need to buy a dark wizard, because in the 5-7, once you unlock the Polyjuice, it already comes with the four Hogwarts founders, and one of them (Salazar Slytherin) is a dark wizard.

Now, you must know that the dark magic is allowed only at the "Back to Hogwarts" phase, in Part 2 of year 7. Right before you enter this phase, you may try to use Slytherin for dark magic, and it will work. After that, it's just important to have a key character, like Griphook, Bogrode or Ms. Cole, and a strong character, like Arthur Weasley (he can fix muggle objects), and you are able to explore the hole game.

I already did 100% of both 1-4 and 5-7.