# Can Narcissa Malfoy use dark magic in LEGO: Harry Potter Years 5-7?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I bought Narcissa assuming I could use her to unlock dark magic bonuses in the game, but when I cast at those areas, nothing happens, and a message comes up telling me I need to know dark magic. It makes no sense to me that she wouldn't be a dark witch.

Answer (score 2):

Even within the Harry Potter universe, there are reasons to believe that just because someone is bad or not nice, [they are not necessarily a dark wizard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/what-constitutes-a-dark-wizard/7422#7422).

Regardless, in this game, Narcissa is not a dark wizard and cannot be used to unlock any of the dark magic sections of the game.  The earliest available dark wizard is [Bellatrix, available in Year 7, part 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36330/1057).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I knew about Bellatrix but didn't have enough coins to get her yet, so I was hoping Narcissa would work. It's a bit weird also, Snape was a dark wizard in years 1-4 but not 5-7. So I don't think it's necessary consistent.